# Firefox "already read it" extension?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

There are a lot of save-to-read extensions for Firefox, for example,  [Read it Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7661/) or [save-to-read](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/161878/).

Is there "read-it" extensions for Firefox which I mean an extension that could record the selected web pages as having already been read, the length I have visited it, the how many times I've visited etc, better if I could categorize these pages.

Anyway, I think I am looking for something like a web page browse recorder. But not the history., it is up to me to select which page to record. Also the extension should provide features that allow me to analysis my browse activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some extensions that could achieve what you're looking for (even if not **exactly** what you're looking for):

- [DejaClick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3262/) lets you record your browsing activities and replay them; it acts a bit like a bookmark on steroids;
- [Infoaxe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9412/) needs you to have an account, but it provides some useful and peculiar features (like being able to see pages you were looking at while having a specific page open);
- [RescueTime](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/123901/) provides some interesting statistical capabilities, and it lets you compare your browsing habits to the rest of the world.

Maybe a combination of these (and others, for what matters) extensions could meet your needs.